# Pegged orders vs Cancel/Replace

Tags: market-data, fx, market-microstructure, market-making

Anyone with real experience between these two types? 
Trying to use Pegged orders for an hft strategy (on forex) and wanted to know if someone could tell me advantages / disadvantages to use them instead of the common cancel / Replace

Answer (score 1):

I would say that generally it depends on the frequency of the orders you intend to send to your providers. If you have a cancel strategy to cancel market orders that aren't filled, as the market moves, then use market orders. If you have a lower frequency strategy where you don't intend to cancel orders, then use pegged orders, which are basically limit orders. This is to keep your providers happy with order frequencies.

Other than that I suppose a limit order allows you to specify an execution price - barring slippage - anywhere, as opposed to a market order which is either executed at market by your provider, or a bid / offer is put in the book (basically like a limit order) which may or may not be executed before you cancel.

Since a private dealer isn't legally required to make a market, then you aren't required to submit market orders... which could be an advantage depending on what your trading strategy is.